# Why the table.addcell(cell) will just display html code int iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, itext, cell

I'm currently trying to export gridview to pdf file.

My code is:

```
public void GvExportPDF(GridView gvListing, string fileName,int TotalColumns)
{
        http.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        http.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= " + fileName + ".pdf");

        http.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        gvListing.AllowPaging = false;

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(TotalColumns);

        foreach (GridViewRow rows in gvListing.Rows)
        {
            if (rows.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                    cell.Phrase = new Phrase(getCellText(rows.Cells[i]));
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }
            }
            else if (rows.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image Image1 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)rows.FindControl("Image1");
                string url = Image1.ImageUrl;
                Image1.Visible = false;

                iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(new Uri(url)); 
                jpg.ScaleToFit(8f, 10f);
                jpg.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        table.AddCell(jpg);
                    else
                    {

                        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(getCellText(rows.Cells[i]))));


                        table.AddCell(cell);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        //gvListing.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, http.Response.OutputStream);
        try
        {
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.Add(table);
        }
        catch (DocumentException dex)
        {
            //http.Response.Write(dex.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dex.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ioex)
        {
            //http.Response.Write(ioex.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ioex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //http.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            pdfDoc.Close();
            //http.Response.Write(StyleOfExportTable());
            http.Response.Output.Write(pdfDoc);
            http.Response.End();
        }
    }

    private string getCellText(TableCell cell)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cell.Text);

        foreach (Control c in cell.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Visible)
            {
                string controlText = getTextProperty(c);
                if (controlText != null)
                {
                    if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(" ");
                    sb.Append(controlText);
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private string getTextProperty(object o)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperty("Text");
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            MethodInfo getMethod = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
            if (getMethod != null)
            {
                return (string)getMethod.Invoke(o, null);
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

It can export pdf and can export the total column I want but besides the image, others cell just display the html code `<table><tr><td>text</td></tr></table>`.

What is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using `sw`, `hw`, `sr` and `htmlparser` or is that from something else?

Comment: ya, Chris Hass. I'm using htmlparser and stringbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a direct answer but I can tell you with almost certainty that the problem is going to be with whatever you are doing to set the contents of the `PdfPCell`. The core of iTextSharp has no concept of HTML, almost all commands are PDF-based with a couple of .Net-specific ones in there. There *is* a parser that turns HTML into PDF-based commands but you aren't using it. So whatever you are doing to get a cell's contents is returning HTML which iTextSharp is treating as a string literal. You will either need to have your algorithms return text only or use the `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList` to convert the HTML to iTextSharp objects.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but where should i put this?